# nginx: How to get the search query params ?

Tags: nginx

Let's say that I have the following HTTP request that is being handled by nginx:
http://myserver.com/find/something?a=1&b=2&c=3

How can I access the value of param 'a' in the search query? I want nginx to give me 'nil' if the parameter is not found.

I tried "ngx.var.a" but Nginx treated it just as a string.

Answer (score 0):

`$arg_a` can do the work.

e.g.

```
if ($arg_a == 1) { 
    // ....
}
```

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Answers on SO are supposed to be complete, explaining the solution and possibly referring to part of the (official) documentation.